# How to skip Python source files in readthedocs Sphinx build

Tags: python, build, python-sphinx, blender, read-the-docs

How can I tell readthedocs not to load any Python files located at top root folder?

Background: I would like readthedocs to build Sphinx documentation for a Blender Python add-on, hosted on github. I have created docs folder in the repository for Sphinx files. I can build Sphinx docs OK on my local computer (in docs directory), but the build on readthedocs fails on error

```
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bvtknodes/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bvtknodes/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bvtknodes/checkouts/latest/inspect.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'
```

The reason for this error was that there was `inspect.py` module located at root directory, so readthedocs setup process loaded that instead of system version of inspect module. When I renamed my inspect.py to b_inspect.py, then the docs building process finished properly at readthedocs. However this is just a workaround, is there a better solution?

**Original wrong interpretation:** It seems that readthedocs is trying to inspect `__init__.py` (located at top folder level and can't be moved from there to a subfolder) contents and build fails when it can't `import bpy`. AFAIK there is no way to install bpy module via pip (but I wouldn't want to do that anyway). I'd like readthedocs to ignore all python files. `language = None` and `extensions` list in `docs/conf.py` is empty. I've also set "Python configuration file" setting in readthedocs Advanced Settings to `docs/conf.py`. Thanks!

Here is [link to readthedocs build which failed](https://readthedocs.org/projects/bvtknodes/builds/10564032/).

Comment: Cannot reproduce or help without further information. Please include a link to the failed build so we can see the failure and troubleshoot.

Comment: OK, link added.

Comment: I think the issue is that RTD cannot find your `docs/conf.py` file. In your RTD configuration, go to Admin > Advanced Settings, and enter `docs/conf.py` for "Python configuration file". As a side note, and if that setting does not work, I would suggest that you put your source code into a nested folder `src/projectname` to separate docs from code. That could be an issue with RTD, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already set "Python configuration file", and it is unfortunately not an option to move code to a subfolder. I wonder is there some way to stop readthedocs from parsing `__init__.py` if it can't import a library?

Comment: Have you tried searching the [RTD issue tracker](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org)? In general having source code at the root of your project is a bad idea.